# Rails: simple_form adding peer fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple_form with bootstrap, and am mostly working the horizontal layout.

I'd like to occasionally add other fields to the right of fields in the main horizontal column, but am having trouble positing them. Of course I could stop using **:class => 'form-horizontal'** and position them myself, but I was wondering if anyone knew an easy way to add fields to the right of simple_form fields.

I tried using bootstrap positioning, but it broke the simple_form horizontal layout.

For example, see the code below. I would like the **Apply** button to be immediately to the right of the input field. I also have other use cases where I would like to position a second field to the right.

I used the **pull-right** attribute but it takes it to the right of the page. I would like the button immediately to the right of the input field, with some spacing. Is there a simple way of doing this without writing my own CSS?

```
<%= link_to 'Apply', apply_primer3_defaults_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary pull-right', :remote => true, :id => 'apply_btn' %>
<%= f.input :primer3_default, :collection => Primer3Setting.pluck(:description), include_blank: false,:title => 'Primer 3 Default' %>
```

I've added a screenshot to help illustrate the problem. I'd like the **Apply** button to come after the **Primer 3 Std Defaults** drop down. I will also add a field to the right of the **Status** dropdown.

[image]

**EDIT**

Added changes based on **kikicarbonel's** answer (in erb). It's kind of working, but is pretty verbose.

#### Batch Details:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@batch, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <%= f.input :name, input_html: { value: User.find(@batch.user_id).name }, :disabled => true %>
      </div>
      <div class="span12">
        <%= f.input :status, :collection => Batch::STATUS_OPTIONS %>
      </div>
      <div class="span12">
        <%= f.input :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <%= f.input :primer3_default, :collection => Primer3Setting.pluck(:description), include_blank: false,:title => 'Primer 3 Default' %>
      </div>
    <div class="span4 offset2">
      <%= link_to 'Apply', apply_primer3_defaults_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :remote => true, :id => 'apply_btn' %>
      </div>
      </div class="span12">
        <%= f.input :details, :input_html => { :class => "span6", :rows => 5 } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The screenshot is below. When I use **offset1** the fields are touching. It looks like I'll have to craft some custom css to do what I need without all that markup.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use simple_form whit bootstrap css without implements your custom css you can use code like this (i prefer to use haml, but works similarly in erb):

```
= simple_form_for(@example) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    .row
      .span4
        = f.input :title
      .span4.offset2
        = f.input :version
```

The result:

title: bla...bla...bla   version: xxx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added a modified version above as an edit.